# PHP message body looking scattered

Tags: php, html, css

I am stuck, don't know what I am doing wrong, I made a simple PHP mail script, it send properly but what I created on localhost is different from what I am seeing in my inbox when I upload to my server and run tests. NOTE: I created the raw form like that before embedding in my email script. [image: THIS IS WHAT I CREATED] , this is what I am getting in my email inbox when running tests [image: WHAT I GET IN EMAIL INBOX AS RESULT] . Please what am i doing wrong.

```
     $emailTo = $receiver;  
$emailFrom = $sender;

$emailSubject = "Receipt from Example Ltd [$r_reference]";

if($data['success'] == true){

    
$message = '<html><body>'; //I CREATED THIS MESSAGE BODY IN HTML, WORKS WELL BUT MALFUNCTIONING ON EMAIL
$message .= '<div style="width:100%;margin-top:7%;"><div align="center"><h1 style="font-size:1.3em!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;"><img src="https://www.examaple.com/images/example.jpg" alt="Password Change" style="height:40px;width:40px;" /></h1><small style="font-size: 12px;     color: #555555;  line-height: 14px; font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">If you have any issues with this payment, kindly reply to this email or send an email to <br/><a href="mailto:store@example.com" target="_blank" style="color:#50a1f7;">store@example.com</a></small><h1>';
$message .= '<div style="width:510px;border:0.5px solid #ededed;margin-top:25px;height:510px;"><div style="height:180px;  background: #d14836;"><div align="center" style="position:absolute;width:40%;margin-top:50px;"><p style="    margin: 0 auto;     max-width: 300px;     font-size: 18px;  color:#fff;   line-height: 18px;     text-align: center;       font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">Zuwi int"l company Ltd received an outstanding unpaid invoice for</p><br/><h1 style="  margin: 0 auto;     max-width: 300px;     font-size: 36px;  color:#fff;   line-height: 18px;     text-align: center;  font-weight:bold;     font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">NGN 12,000.00</h1></div></div><p style="word-wrap: break-word!important;margin-bottom:-8px!important;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;"><b style="color:#555555;">Transaction Details</b> </p><br/>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #dbdbdb;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .='<tr><td> </td></tr><br/><div style="margin-top:10px;position:absolute;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;border-bottom:0.5px solid #ededed;width:33%;padding-bottom:32px;"><div style="margin-left:0px;position:absolute;color:#555555;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;"> Reference </div> <div style="margin-left:65%;position:absolute;width:50%;color:#555555;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;width:50%;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">'.$r_reference.'</div></div><br/><div style="margin-top:45px;position:absolute;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;border-bottom:0.5px solid #ededed;width:33%;padding-bottom:35px;"><div style="margin-left:0px;position:absolute;color:#555555;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;"> Date </div> <div style="margin-left:65%;position:absolute;width:50%;color:#555555;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;width:50%;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;"> '.$r_date.' </div></div><br/><div style="margin-top:85px;position:absolute;margin-left:2%;margin-right:2%;border-bottom:0.5px solid #ededed;width:33%;padding-bottom:40px;"><div style="margin-left:0px;position:absolute;color:#555555;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;"> Method </div> <div style="margin-left:62%;color:#555555;font-weight:bold;position:absolute;width:50%;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">Pay on delivery </div></div>';
$message .= '<div style="margin-top:33%;"><p style="font-size: 16px;     color: #555555;  line-height: 14px; font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">Zuwi intl company Ltd</p> <p style="margin-top:-10px;"><a href="mailto:store@example.com" target="_blank" style="color:#50a1f7;font-size:14px;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">store@example.com</a></p></div></div></div></div>';
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: <$emailFrom>" . "\r\n";
mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $message, $headers);

$data['success'] = true;

json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Feels like your styling is not good. Have you considered using a stylesheet?

Comment: @progrAmmar , from what I found out you, cant use external style in email, it is inline. Inline is bad for coding.

Comment: or third party styling like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: would look into that @ChristianMark

Comment: You should create a table structure for email layout with inline style.

Comment: @Shasha as ChristianMark Suggested, you can use the bootstrap or others like it to style your HTML. Even if you are using inline styles, I recommend first test them out on a test page and check the results, make a HTML file and see the results in the browser. If they are to your liking then put that code in your PHP Mail body.

Comment: @progrAmmar that is what I did at first, i created them first in html confused why it behaving this way.

Comment: Are you opening your e-mail in the browser or other Mail software i.e. Outlook, Thunderbird etc.

Comment: For bootstrap email template visit this link. https://github.com/advancedrei/BootstrapForEmail/blob/master/template.html

Comment: @progrAmmar , in my GMail for test, but built it in html form from notepad++ and shows like the image i shared above, dont know why it is behaving this way.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Thanks Khalid on it.

Comment: @Shasha very welcome.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid not so good let me bend debugging my code maybe one night would solve it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your code into table structure then it will work. I just change your code into table format now you can add style whatever you want.

**Browser View**

[image]

**Remember**
For best view use table structure for the email template.

```
$message = '<html><body>'; //I CREATED THIS MESSAGE BODY IN HTML, WORKS WELL BUT MALFUNCTIONING ON EMAIL
$message .= '<table style="width:100%;margin-top:7%;"><tr><td><div align="center"><h1 style="font-size:1.3em!important;margin-bottom:15px!important;"><img src="https://www.ogafriday.com/images/zuwii.jpg" alt="Password Change" style="height:40px;width:40px;" /></h1><small style="font-size: 12px;     color: #555555;  line-height: 14px; font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">If you have any issues with this payment, kindly reply to this email or send an email to <br/><a href="mailto:store@ogafriday.com" target="_blank" style="color:#50a1f7;">store@ogafriday</a></small><h1>';
$message .= '<div style="width:510px;border:0.5px solid #ededed;margin-top:25px;height:510px;"><div style="height:180px;  background: #d14836;"><br><p style=" margin: 0 auto; max-width: 300px;     font-size: 18px;  color:#fff;   line-height: 18px;     text-align: center; font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">Zuwi int"l company Ltd received an outstanding unpaid invoice for</p><br/><h1 style="  margin: 0 auto;     max-width: 300px;     font-size: 36px;  color:#fff;   line-height: 18px;     text-align: center;  font-weight:bold;     font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Roboto","Oxygen","Ubuntu","Cantarell","Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;">NGN 12,000.00</h1></div><p style="word-wrap: break-word!important;margin-bottom:-8px!important;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;"><b style="color:#555555;">Transaction Details</b> </p><br/>';
$message .= '<table width="90%" style="margin:0px auto;" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">Reference</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;" align="right">You text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">Date</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;" align="right">You text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">Method</td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;" align="right">You text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><br><p>Zuwi intl company Ltd</p><a href="mailto:store@ogafriday">store@ogafriday</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>';
$message .= "</td></tr></table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Look into this @Shasha